# Android programatically set width/height of key on custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom softkeyboard. I know the method `Keyboard.getKeys()` returns a List of Key objects. However I am not sure how to use this to set the width and height of a particular key on the softkeyboard.

I looked through the documentation and there is a `setKeyHeight()` method, however it is a protected method and I do not think it can be used to set the height of a specific key.

So, how do I programmatically set the height of a specific key for a custom Android soft keyboard?